# Application menus missing in gnome-flashback

Tags: gnome, appmenu

I have activated gnome-flashback on 15.10 (wily). Since I switched from Unity to gnome-flashback the application menus (File, Edit, View, ...) are missing!

My actual workaround is to install indicator-appmenu-applet to have the menus in the upper panel.

[image: the menus in the appmenu-applet]

How can I move the menus back to the application window?

Update:
After testing a little bit longer I found another very strange workaround/behavior:

1. open unity-tweak-tool
2. killall nautilus
3. select another theme in the unity-tweak-tool and switch back to Ambiance.
4. open Nautilus. **The menus are back!** :-)
   [image: the menus on the right place]
5. logout and login again
6. **the menus are gone again!** :-(

What's going on here?

Comment: some apps have it while others dont. I tried your solution but it didnt work. Chrome and Firefox are still missing the menus.